# game of throwing 200 die [see desc.]

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is dice game question about probability.

Play a game with $2$ die. What is the probability of getting a sum greater than $7$?

I know how the probability for this one is easy, $\cfrac{1+2+3+4+5}{36}=\cfrac 5{12}$.

I don't know how to solve the follow-up question:

Play a game with $200$ die. What is the probability of getting a sum greater than $700$?

Comment: Are you sure you understood the case with 2 dices? If so, you should be able to answer for 200. If not, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: In the case of 2 die there are 36 possible outcomes. How many of them are good outcomes?

Comment: The good outcomes should be 1+2+3+4+5=15, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the probability for two die to get a sum greater than 7 is $$\cfrac{1+2+3+4+5}{36}=\cfrac 5{12}.$$ For $200$ die it is too hard to calculate the required probaility exactly. A reasonable way is to choose Central Limit Theorem and obtain the approximate answer using normal approximation to the distribution of the sum.

Let $X_i$ be the points we get at $i$-th throw. Then $\mathbb P(X_i=k)=1/6$, $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{200}$ are independent and identically distributed r.v's with mean $\mathbb E[X_1]=3.5$ and variance $\text{Var}[X_1]=35/12$. By CLT for $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$,
$$
\mathbb P\left(S_{200}>700\right) = \mathbb P\Biggl(\frac{S_{200}-200\cdot \mathbb E[X_1]}{\sqrt{200 \text{Var}[X_1]}}>\underbrace{\frac{700-200\cdot 3.5}{\sqrt{200\cdot\frac{35}{12}}}}_{0}\Biggr) \approx \mathbb P(Z >0)=0.5
$$
where $Z$ has standard normal distribution.

You can also give the same approximate answer to this question without CLT. It it obvious that the distribution of $S_{200}$ is symmetric w.r.t. $700$: it is equally probable to get sum $200$ and $1200$, $201$ and $1199$, ..., $699$ and $701$. Therefore $$\mathbb P(S_{200}>700)=\mathbb P(S_{200}<700)=\frac{1-\mathbb P(S_{200}=700)}2$$
And the probabililty $\mathbb P(S_{200}=700)$ is sufficiently small, so $\mathbb P(S_{200}>700)$ is close to $0.5$

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest that one should attempt the computation by hand, and I'm pretty sure this is not what you are asked to do, but the following MATLAB code returns

$$ 0.49174766008476854489594153068254 $$

for the probability of rolling a number greater than $700$.  It does so in less than 5 s.

```
poly1 = poly2sym(sym([ones(1,6), 0]) / sym(6));
poly200 = poly1^200;
c200 = coeffs(poly200, 'All'); % from highest to lowest degree
pmf = c200(end:-1:1);          % from lowest to highest degree
pr = vpa(sum(pmf(702:end)));   % pmf(i+1) == Pr(X=i)
```

The computation is carried out exactly until the call to `vpa` returns a result accurate to 32 digits (the number of digits may be increased).  Numerical convolution (with `conv`) is much faster, of course, and while it does not boast the same accuracy, it's not too shabby:

$$ 0.491747660084763 \enspace.$$

A look at the graph of the exact and approximate PDFs confirms that the normal approximation suggested by @NCh is more than adequate for most uses.

[image: exact vs approximate pmf]

Indeed, if we apply a [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction):

```
1-normcdf(0.5/sqrt(200*35/12))
```

we obtain $0.491741700046665$.